# Slow countDocuments

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongodb-atlas

So we are having a small issue with

```
countDocuments
```

It seems that they are slower then `.count()` function.

I am wondering how do I speed it up?

the query i am running is

```
query = { location:{ $geoWithin:{ $centerSphere: [ [ parseFloat(docs.location.coordinates[0]), parseFloat(docs.location.coordinates[1])], 5 / 6378.1] } } };
```

The script I am running

```
var dquery = Q.countDocuments(query).exec(function(err, count){

(Then I need to run the following)

 if(count > 0 ){
                          var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * count);
                          //START ADQUERY
                          console.error(count);
                          console.error(random);
                          var aquery = A.findOne(query).skip(random);
}

});
```

It taking approx 3-4 seconds to run the first part, and because we are injecting the response into

```
stream.on
```

However it seems to crash the stream because of the query speed.

I am wondering if any one would have a solution to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

`count` looks at collection metadata and provides an estimated result.

`countDocuments` executes the query and provides an accurate result.

The performance of `countDocuments` is similar to performance of `find` with the same arguments.

You need to have appropriate indexes in place, etc., same as for find.

Comment: But 15 seconds to return countDocuments that a long time.

Comment: If you have a lot of data it has to scan all the documents to match your query, indexes will speed this up greatly at the cost of losing some write performance, but negligible versus query performance increase. Try adding `.explain()` at the end of your query, it'll output the actions it needs to take to run it. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/explain-results/index.html